# What is the difference between these two python command line? (python -m module_name vs python module_name.py)

Tags: python, command-line

I know that I can run `.py` file in terminal by using command line:

```
python module_name.py
```

I can also use

```
python -m module_name
```

Both can run a module. So, I wanted to that what's the between difference both command line ?

Comment: Have you tried to find out by yourself (i.e. `python --help`)?

Comment: I have run both two commands, but the output seem the same: terminals will run the .py file.